# Can I override standard Ionic (3) components?

Tags: angular, ionic3

So there is a standard UI component - ion-range:
https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/src/components/range/range.ts
http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#range

and I want to make it "vertical range", then code wise I don't see a problem:

- modify SCSS to perform transform: rotate(-90) for the component
- introduce "vertical" boolean property
- if set to true use Y coordinates instead of X (see current.x in the source code)

**Question - how can I "extend" or override methods and properties of a standard ionic component?** is this at all possible?

Feels like the only option is to use a web component if I want to get vertical ion-range.

Comment: Maybe **[this post](https://www.joshmorony.com/using-a-directive-to-modify-the-behaviour-of-an-ionic-component/)** could help...

Comment: Yes I went through Josh's course and this specific article before I posted this question. I think what Josh does in his example - he "adds" functionality on top of what original component is providing. But I am after "overriding" here;). Modifying a method in a "class" (forgot how we call those in js). I read this article here: https://scotch.io/tutorials/component-inheritance-in-angular-2 but again not sure how applicable this is to Ionic? how does Ionic's inheritance model works?

Comment: @SergeyRudenko Did you find any solution? I want to extend ion-label.

Comment: Hey, not really I was not looking further into it at that time;/